# Chain rule of derivatives (higher dimensions)

Tags: calculus

If $T:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$, $T(x,y)=(x+a,y+b)$.  How can I calculate the partial derivatives of $F\circ T$ using chain rule for higher derivatives?

Am I right if I write (in variable $x$): $(F\circ T)'(x,y)=F'(T(x,y))\cdot T'(x,y)$?

I would like to show that $F_X(a,b)=F_X^T(0,0)$. Where $F^T=F\circ T.$

But I couldn't prove that using the chain rule of the derivatives, I need help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$F_X^T(0,0) = {F^{T'}}(0,0){e_1} = F'(T(0,0))T'(0,0){e_1} = F'(a,b){I_2}{e_1} = F'(a,b){e_1} = {F_X}(a,b)$$

where $e_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}$ and $I_{2}$ is the $2\times2$ identity matrix.

Comment: Thank you for the edit Peter. I couldn't figure out what I messed up on.

Comment: I couldn't either. I pasted the code in a coder that redid the code. It compiled allright, which is weird.

Comment: Oh that is weird. Well thank you for helping!

Comment: I didn't understand why $T'(0,0)=I_2$

Comment: Since $T$ is differentiable then $T'(0,0)=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial(x+a)}{\partial x}(0,0)&\frac{\partial(x+a)}{\partial y}(0,0)\\
\frac{\partial(y+b)}{\partial x}(0,0)&\frac{\partial(y+b)}{\partial y}(0,0)\\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$) You are right if $F'$ is the gradient (transposed) and $T'$ is the Jacobian matrix.  Everything is easier if you use this derivative formulation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions, though it appears there is no proof of chain rule there.

---

Oh I see the question now... Same as user71352, but I'll just post a quick point:

So $T'$ seems to be the identity regardless of $(a,b)$. $T(0,0) = (a,b)$. Thus, chain rule gives directly that $D(F^T)(0,0) = F'(T(0,0)) T'(0,0) = F'(a,b)$

Comment: but how can I prove: $F_X(a,b)=F_X^T(0,0)$?

Comment: Completely misread your post, sorry :)

Comment: ok, no problem :)

Comment: I didn't understand why you said that $T'(0,0)=(1,1)$, for me $T'(x,y)=(1,0)$

Comment: @user42912  The derivative of $T$ at $0$ has to satisfy $T(h) \sim T(0) + T'(0) h$ (not exactly... look up formal definition as per link, $T'(0)$ necessarily is a $2\times 2$ matrix). Since $T(0)=(a,b)$, and $T(h) = (a+h_1,b+h_2)$, we can verify directly that $T'(0) = Id_2$ satisfies the right criteria.

Comment: yes, thank you!